# Unable to perform hybris SOLR Indexing

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Unable to perform SOLR Indexing. Getting the following error.
Any suggestion to fix will be helpful.

```
de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: Indexer worker failed. Max number of retries in total has been reached
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.doExecute(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:97) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.AbstractIndexerStrategy.doExecute(AbstractIndexerStrategy.java:165) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.AbstractIndexerStrategy.execute(AbstractIndexerStrategy.java:124) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexerService.performFullIndex(DefaultIndexerService.java:68) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.cron.SolrIndexerJob.indexItems(SolrIndexerJob.java:78) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.cron.SolrIndexerJob.performIndexingJob(SolrIndexerJob.java:57) [solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.multicountry.solr.indexer.cron.impl.MulticountrySolrIndexerJob.performIndexingJob(MulticountrySolrIndexerJob.java:72) [classes/:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.cron.AbstractIndexerJob.perform(AbstractIndexerJob.java:40) [solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob.performCronJob(ServicelayerJob.java:38) [processingserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.execute(Job.java:1390) [processingserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:814) [processingserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.access$1(Job.java:767) [processingserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job$JobRunable.run(Job.java:686) [processingserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.util.threadpool.PoolableThread.internalRun(PoolableThread.java:208) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:135) [coreserver.jar:?]
Caused by: de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: Indexer worker failed. Max number of retries in total has been reached
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.runWorkers(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:153) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.doExecute(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:93) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to unregister thread with [id=1269 name=solr indexer thread]. Is not present in thread registry
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.runWorkers(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:140) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.doExecute(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:93) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to unregister thread with [id=1269 name=solr indexer thread]. Is not present in thread registry
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:721) ~[guava-21.0.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.ThreadRegistry.unregister(ThreadRegistry.java:94) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.unregisterThread(RegistrableThread.java:125) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.unregisterThread(RegistrableThread.java:118) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.workers.impl.DefaultIndexerWorker.run(DefaultIndexerWorker.java:174) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
INFO  [update-lscob2bpbIndex-cronJob::de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob] (update-lscob2bpbIndex-cronJob) [SolrIndexerJob] Started indexer cronjob.
INFO  [update-lscob2bpbIndex-cronJob::de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob] (update-lscob2bpbIndex-cronJob) [SolrIndexerJob] Finished indexer cronjob.
```

Comment: Can you please share your solr server configuration from backoffice? Also is this uel works for you? http://localhost:8983/solr

Comment: Thanks Nirmal. I posted the SOLR configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the configuration of SOLR [SOLR Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i8f7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making your solr configuration as embedded, if you are not using standalone solr. It seems like hybris is not able to connect with your solr server.

Answer (score 0):

ensure solr running? -> npnt -lpnt or nmap commands to check the port and try hitting the solr in the browser on port 8983 with the IP of the host,
confirm solr is accessible in the browser on the host you are running commerce server on.
if using embedded check did you add solr server in localextensions.xml

*OP might have solved this already, but I am replying here so the next person can find this helpful.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Solr is trying to index property that doesn't match its type.

Example: indexing string (12 cm) to double (should be only 12).

Solr is saying it tried to index that value (default is 3) x times. So there is problem in your data.